# Dataset with 4D images: expected Byte but found Float

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have some MRI scans that I want to create a custom PyTorch `Dataset` out of. Each scan is a set of 31 RGB images, so the scans are 4 dimensional `(Channels, Depth, Height, Width)`. The images are `.png`, and each scan is a folder with 31 images. After loading the scans, I tried passing them through a `Conv3D`, but I got an error (full traceback at the end):

```py
x = torch.unsqueeze(dataset[0][0], 0)
x.shape  # torch.Size([1, 3, 31, 512, 512])
m = nn.Conv3d(3,12,3)
out = m(x)
```

> RuntimeError: expected scalar type Byte but found Float

How can I solve this error? I think it happens because I load the scans in as a NumPy array of NumPy arrays, but I don't know how else to do it. How can I load 4D image data into a custom `Dataset`?

Here's my custom `Dataset` class:

```
import torch
import os
import pandas as pd
from skimage import io
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class TrainImages(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.annotations = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotations)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # The folder containing the images of a scan
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(self.annotations.iloc[index, 0]).zfill(5))
        # Create a tensor out of a numpy array of numpy arrays, where each array is an image in the scan
        image = torch.from_numpy(np.array([np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(str(img_path),"rgb-"+str(i)+".png"))) for i in range(31)]).transpose(3,0,1,2).astype(np.uint8))
        y_label = torch.tensor(int(self.annotations.iloc[index, 1]))
        return (image, y_label)
```

Full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-f3c4dfbd5496> in <module>
      1 m=nn.Conv3d(3,12,3)
----> 2 out=m(x)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    571                             self.dilation, self.groups)
    572         return F.conv3d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 573                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    574 
    575 

RuntimeError: expected scalar type Byte but found Float
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message can be confusing, but the problem is that your data has the `Byte` type, while conv3d expects `Float`. You need to change from `np.uint8` to `np.float32` in the `__getitem__(...)` of your `Dataset`:

```py
image = torch.from_numpy(np.array([
    np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(str(img_path),"rgb-"+str(i)+".png")))
    for i in range(31)
]).transpose(3, 0, 1, 2).astype(np.float32))  # <<< changed from np.uint8 to float32
```

or, cast `x` to `Float` before passing to the model:

```py
out = m(x.float())
```

Note that if you use a transform like `.ToTensor()` later on, this problem will be solved as well.